# Micropython-machine package installation Error

Tags: python, pip, micropython

I can't install micropython-machine package.

I'm installing Package Locally.

`>pip install micropython-machine-0.2.tar.gz`

Or

`>pip install micropython-machine`

Throwing error like Below

`>error: file "setup.py" not found for legacy project`

i Think this Package Has No Setup.py File......

Anyone have Solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you dont need machine package for your device separately, as it is included by default for each micropython port